# Error: Callback for provider type credentials not supported

Tags: nginx, next.js, next-auth, amazon-lightsail

So I have my Next.JS app hosting on Lightsail with Nginx proxy, I've just done setupping the domain for my app and it's already online. Somehow when I try to log in it's giving me an error saying *"Error: Callback for provider type credentials not supported"*
[image]

But it works when I try to open and log in with the public IP. I guess it's something wrong with the Nginx configuration but I'm not sure which one. Maybe someone can help me with this issue?

I tried to create a custom server from Next.JS and already tried to change some Nginx configuration but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you show us your `/api/auth/[...nextauth].js` file?

Comment: Hi @juliomalves , here's my `[...nextauth].js` file https://ibb.co/0XKkGVj 
Hope you can help

Comment: Hi, was this issue ever resolved?

Comment: @user3748198 it seems there's something wrong in the NGINX configuration files, I rewrite the entire file and it seems working now

Comment: @newDev33 Please what was the configurqtion you put on nginx