# Next Auth - Error: Callback for provider type credentials not supported

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I've been into the following issue in Nextjs

The error comes into the production site which is hosted on Lightsail, all the routes are working fine except the login

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74327562/error-callback-for-provider-type-credentials-not-supported)

My auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts file looks like this:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import axios from 'axios';

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: 'Credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: {},
                password: {},
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                console.log('api url: ', process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL);
                try {
                    const res = await axios.post(
                        `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/auth/login`,
                        {
                            email: credentials?.email,
                            password: credentials?.password,
                        }
                    );
                    return res.data;
                } catch (err: any) {
                    if (
                        err?.response?.data &&
                        err?.response?.data.errorType === 'emailVerification'
                    ) {
                        throw new Error(JSON.stringify(err?.response?.data));
                    } else {
                        throw new Error(
                            err?.response?.data?.message || 'unable to login'
                        );
                    }
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: '/login',
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ user, token }: { user: any; token: any }) {
            if (user) {
                return { token: user.token, user: user.data };
            } else {
                return { token: token.token, user: token.user };
            }
        },
        async session({ session, token }: { session: any; token: any }) {
            session.user = {
                ...token.user,
                accessToken: token.token,
            };
            return session;
        },
    },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Trying to resolve it for so long, any help would highly be appreciated